# Regular Expression for semicolon

Tags: java, regex

I need to develop a code to check the String has got any Semicolon. And charector can be in any flavor.

```
            Charector                   : ;
            Ascii                        : 59
            HTML Entity (decimal)        : &#59
            HTML Entity (hex)            : &#x3b
            Alt                          : 059
            Alt                          : 59
            UTF-8 (hex)                  : 0x3B (3b)
            UTF-8 (binary)               : 00111011
            UTF-16 (hex)                 : 0x003B (003b)
            UTF-16 (decimal)             : 59
            UTF-32 (hex)                 : 0x0000003B (3b)
            UTF-32 (decimal)             : 59

    etc...
Is there a proper way with regular expression , where I can check all flavors of semicolon.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings don't have an encoding. So you need to just check on `myString.contains(";")`

Comment: Comparing only ";" is I know, but I want a comparison to check all flavors of Semicolon(May be my english is wrong). What I mean a String can be "xyz;" or "0x0000003B" , my comparison should return true saying Semi colon is there in the String. So I thought to use the Regular expression.

Comment: If the string is "0x0000003B" it is not a semicolon but actually that string. encoding only happens at bytelevel, there should be no need to try to match the string on any of those encodings

Comment: What you mean is Value in String "0x0000003B" is a String representation not Hexadecimal. What happen if I send this to SQL query after "Order By"

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if(yourString.contains(";")){
    // Do things
}
```

Why do you need a regex just to see if it contains one character ?

Comment: Comparing only ";" is I know, but I want a comparison to check all flavors of Semicolon(May be my english is wrong). What I mean a String can be "xyz;" or "0x0000003B" , my comparison should return true saying Semi colon is there in the String. So I thought to use the Regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check for semicolon, all you need to do is:

```
int pos = yourString.indexOf(";");
if (pos != -1) {
  //...semicolon found at position pos
}
```

What do you actually mean by "flavours of semicolon"?

Comment: Comparing only ";" is I know, but I want a comparison to check all flavors of Semicolon(May be my english is wrong). What I mean a String can be "xyz;" or "0x0000003B" , my comparison should return true saying Semi colon is there in the String. So I thought to use the Regular expression.

Comment: Well, but what would then be an expected result for "0x0000003B;"? Is that one semicolon or two?